# GrapQHL Apollo Server, extract values and use them in a resolver

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I have a GraphQL API where I request data. The requested data contains ids based on which I want to call further data and resolve in a separate resolver. Let's assume I have a schema like this:

```
type Query {
    catchSomeData: [SomeData]!
    specialTypes: [SpecialType]!
}

type SomeData {
    someDataId: Int!
    key: String!
    specialTypeIdA: Int! @collect
    specialTypeIdB: Int! @collect
}

type SpecialType {
    specialTypeId: Int!
    name: String!
    someValue: String!
}
```

The query looks like this:

```
query {
    catchSomeData {
        someDataId
        key
        specialTypeIdA
        specialTypeIdB
    }
    specialTypes {
        specialTypeId
        name
        someValue
    }
}
```

When `catchSomeData` is resolved I want all the Ids for `specialTypeIdA` and `specialTypeIdB` to be collected. I use the Ids to fetch data from a database in the resolver of `specialTypes`.

I managed do built a directive to collect the Ids and store it in the `context` variable. Since I use Apollo Server the resolvers for `catchSomeData` and `specialTypes` are executed concurrently. So when the code for `specialTypes` is executed the Ids are not yet collected.

Any ideas how to solve the problem in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no you can't do that. Query execution is not guaranteed to happen in order like what you're describing, and the results *are supposed to be* what you're seeing.

But now to just take a step back, it feels like you're approaching this very RESTfully. Instead of having siblings between `catchSomeData` and `specialTypes`, the GraphQL way is to nest these objects:

```
type Query {
    catchSomeData: [SomeData]!
    specialTypes: [SpecialType]!
}

type SomeData {
    someDataId: Int!
    key: String!
    specialTypeIdA: SpecialType!
    specialTypeIdB: SpecialType!
}

type SpecialType {
    specialTypeId: Int!
    name: String!
    someValue: String!
}
```

and then your query would be

```
query {
    catchSomeData {
        someDataId
        key
        specialTypeIdA {
            specialTypeId
            name
            someValue
        }
        specialTypeIdB {
            specialTypeId
            name
            someValue
        }
    }
}
```

or if you don't want to type the nested stuff twice, you could use a fragment:

```
query {
    catchSomeData {
        someDataId
        key
        specialTypeIdA {
            ...specialData
        }
        specialTypeIdB {
            ...specialData
        }
    }
}

fragment specialData on SpecialType {
    specialTypeId: Int!
    name: String!
    someValue: String!
}
```

And then I would recommend you look at [DataLoader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader) for how to do lookups in bulk like that.

Comment: I thought about such a solution, the problem with this is that I need to fetch a lot of specialTypes and a often they are the same. With this approach I will end up with lot's of redundant data. I guess I will need then to request one query, wait for the result to come back, then to extract all the specialTypeIds and send a second query.

Comment: Redundant data, in bytes-over-wire yes, but it's also properly nested in the way that your API consumer wants it to be. If you're having issues with it being "too much data", you might just be querying for too much data. Take a step back: are you actually showing all of this in a single client view? Should you be? Additionally, with GraphQL you should never have to make the client make two calls for the data on a page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutation as it preserves order of root resolvers.